# How can I update shipping methods on checkout with changes in zipcode input?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, zipcode

How can I update shipping methods on checkout with changes in zipcode input?

My shipping methods are not updating with zipcode input change value. Only with page refresh.

Comment: Are your custom shipping or default Magento?

Comment: Yes, I have installed https://bitbucket.org/igor_lm/igorludgero_correiosofflinem2/wiki/Home

Comment: The shipping rates only update when I leave zipcode input empty

Comment: I believe that is a cookie problem, when I clear postcode on cookie (mage-cache-storage) and refresh the page with ctrl+shift+r (google chrome to clear cache) the update shipping rates works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix that editing this function on `shipping.js`:

```
               checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function (shippingAddressData) {
                    /* Custom code to update shipping rates init */
                    if(s_postcode == null){
                        s_postcode = shippingAddressData.postcode;
                    }else{
                        if(shippingAddressData.postcode != s_postcode && shippingAddressData.postcode.length == 9){

                     checkoutDataResolver.resolveEstimationAddress();
                        }else{
                            if(s_postcode != null){
                                shippingAddressData.postcode = s_postcode;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /* Custom code to update shipping rates init */
                    checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddressData);
                });
```

and declarate var:

```
var s_postcode = null;
```